# Ethernet does not work - 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, networking, ethernet

My Ethernet connection does not work. It's not a cable problem (I've used two different cables with no luck), and the Ethernet splitter works for everyone else. Also, the yellow stable light and the flashing green light both show up on the Ethernet port itself. The Ethernet was working at some time in the past, but now it doesn't.

I'm not sure exactly what information I need to provide, but here's (probably) useful stuff:

I'm not using another operating system. I am running and Asus desktop. I have installed (from a homemade install disk) Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. During the re-install process (I re-installed from disk to see if it would help), it showed that the PCI setup was successful. The output of `lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'Eth|net'` is:

`02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8056 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller [11ab:4364] (rev 20)
     Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b.0e0a]
     Kernel driver in use: sky2`

Output of `sudo modprobe -rv sk92lin`:

`modprobe: FATAL: Module sk98lin not found.`

Output of `sudo modprobe -rv sky2`:

`rmmod sky2`

The following message keeps popping up randomly:

`[ <random time> ] sky2 0000:02:00.0 eth0: tk timeout`

Also, I sometimes get this error at startup/shutdown:

`[ <random time> ] sky2 0000:02:00.0: PCI hardware error (0x2010)`

Can anyone help? Also, I'm happy to provide any other necessary information.

EDIT: Here's where I'm going to add my research and its results. I have more, but I can't add more than two links (yet).

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1802235 - Tried everything in there, but nothing worked.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1371247 - I remember seeing a similar error on my computer at some point. However, I don't have a dhconfig.conf file to edit. Opening it in `nano` shows it as a new file. That could also be part of the problem - or another problem entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the `sky2 0000:02:00.0: PCI hardware error (0x2010)` is, in fact, a PCI hardware error.

The two lights on the Ethernet ports indicated that the power was turning on, then off, on, off, etc. Because the Ethernet was supposedly working a few years ago, I've narrowed it down to two issues:

1.) The computer was originally merged with another computer, so that plus moving the computer around may have jostled the cord loose. I'm going to try opening up the desktop and fiddling with it a bit.

2.) The Ethernet is simply broken. That's okay too, since I'm going to get two wireless adapters for Christmas (one for my Raspberry Pi, one to replace the Ethernet if the other solution doesn't work).

I'll comment with an update in case anyone needs it.

UPDATE: The Ethernet port is integrated as part of the motherboard. However, I remember reading something about losing Ethernet after upgrading RAM. The box advertises 1 GB RAM, but I see 4 GB...

**UPDATE 2:** Downgrading to 2 GB RAM worked!

Comment: Are you saying that removing some RAM sticks brought back your Ethernet?

Comment: Yes. See here for an example of this issue: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1461685

Comment: Amazing. Good for you for figuring that one out! :) You might want to highlight your UPDATE 2 (make it bold), so it stands out more.

Comment: It took a week of searching about network configuration, drivers, etc. before I finally came to the simple 5-minute solution. I hope this helps other users as well.